How to replace ref-qualifiers of member functions with concept?
Is it possible to replace following ref-qualifiers with concepts?
That is, instead of
struct S 
{
   void func() && {}
   void func() & {}
};

have something like this
struct S 
{
   void func() requires rvalue_concept< decltype(*this) > {}
   void func() requires lvalue_concept< decltype(*this) > {}
};


Note: This is not a duplicate of How can I make a forwarding-reference parameter bind only to rvalue references?
because my question is about checking whether the struct S is used as an r-value-reference, but the other question is about a function which shall only accept r-value-references.

Perhaps this Explicit object member functions is another way to do it.

Is there some reason you want to avoid using the syntax?

@NicolBolas: I want to apply it actually for the destructor. I guess I have to formulate a new question on SO.


Is it possible to replace ref-qualifiers with concepts?

You can use the explicit object parameter syntax introduced in c++23, which allows us to deduce the type of this.
With that, you could write:
template<typename T>
concept rvalue_concept = std::is_rvalue_reference_v<T&&>;

template<typename T>
concept lvalue_concept = !rvalue_concept<T>;

struct S 
{
    template<typename Self>
    void func(this Self&& self) requires rvalue_concept<Self> 
    {
        std::cout << "rvalue version called\n";
    }

    template<typename Self>
    void func(this Self&& self) requires lvalue_concept<Self> 
    {
        std::cout << "lvalue version called\n";
    }
};

See live demo

Is there some reason you couldn't just write void func(this S&& self); and void func(this S& self);? What's the point of the template there?

@NicolBolas You're right that for this specific case, using void func(this S&& self) and void func(this S& self) would be simpler and achieve the same result. The templated version with concepts offers more flexibility for generic programming scenarios, allowing the function to work with derived classes or in template contexts. However, if that level of generality isn't needed, the non-templated version is indeed more straightforward.
